# Do not allow product of different categories in a cart

Tags: django, satchmo

Satchmo store has products of different categories. For some reason I need to process payments of products of different category using different merchant account. Since this needs to be done asap, the quick solution is not to allow products of different category in the same cart. I read the manual to see if some signals were available which could help me get the type of product when added to cart and then if the cart already has a product from different category, then remove the product newly added and mention this to the user. Is there a better way to get this done quickly? If no, I would like some inputs to help me achieve the above flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ajax and/or decorators. So when user select product you just compare with categories of the products in the cart and if there any display error message. I think it will be only one query to check if there are any items with same category, so add/remove operation will be excess.